# C# - Обработка команд бота

Tags: c#, .net, бот, .net-core

Всем привет. Не могу понять. Как обработать команду? Допустим в `string command` у меня есть слово с командой. Допустим, что `command = "скажи"`. У меня есть 100 классов, каждый из которых отвечает за нужную команду. Как вызвать код, который относится именно к этой команде т.е именно класс `Say`? Я думаю, что использовать `switch` или `if else if` неправильно. Что можно придумать в таком случае?

Comment: Я реализовывать подобное вот посмотрите код. https://bitbucket.org/Andrew_Moryakov/newsribbonbot

Comment: Словарь. Ключ - текст команды, значение - экземпляр соответствующего класса или делегат

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала определимся с тем, какие структуры данных нам могут понадобится. Очвидно, у нас должны быть интерфейсы для команды и для оработчика команды.

```
// Команда и прямая реализация
public interface ICommand
{
    string CommandName { get;}
}

public class Command : ICommand
{
    public Command(string name)
    {
        CommandName = name;
    }
    public string CommandName { get; private set; }
}

// Обработчик команды
public interface ICommandProcessor
{
    void ProcessCommand(ICommand command);
    bool CanProcess(ICommand command);
}
```

Далее, нам нужны 2 простых обработчика. Вот они:

```
public class PrintCommandProc : ICommandProcessor
{
    public bool CanProcess(ICommand command)
    {
        return command.CommandName == "print";
    }

    public void ProcessCommand(ICommand command)
    {
        if (!CanProcess(command)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(command));
        Console.WriteLine($"{command.CommandName} command processed");
    }
}

public class ReadCommandProc : ICommandProcessor
{
    public bool CanProcess(ICommand command)
    {
        return command.CommandName == "read";
    }

    public void ProcessCommand(ICommand command)
    {
        if (!CanProcess(command)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(command));
        Console.WriteLine($"{command.CommandName} command processed");
    }
}
```

Что делать дальше: так как вы не уточнили, могут ли одну и ту же команду обрабатывать несколько обработчиков, я покажу 2 подхода, которые немного отличаются. Причем вы в любой момент сможете заменить один подход другом.

Итак, вариант 1, случай, когда несколько обработчиков МОГУТ обрабатывать одну и ту же команду. 
Для этого создадим композитный обработчик, который будет держать список всех доступых обработчиков:

```
public class CompositeCommandProcessor : ICommandProcessor
{
    ICommandProcessor[] _commandProcs;

    public CompositeCommandProcessor(params ICommandProcessor[] commandProcs)
    {
        _commandProcs = commandProcs;
    }

    public bool CanProcess(ICommand command)
    {
        return _commandProcs.Any(c=>c.CanProcess(command));
    }

    public void ProcessCommand(ICommand command)
    {
        if (!CanProcess(command)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(command));
        foreach (var cp in _commandProcs.Where(c=>c.CanProcess(command)))
            cp.ProcessCommand(command);
    }
}
```

Как видите, эту команду можно инициализировать любым набором обработчиков, а также каждая команда проходит через каждый обработчик. Таким образом, для одной и той же команды можно зарегистрировать несколько обработчиков.

Использование:

```
var commandProc = new CompositeCommandProcessor(new PrintCommandProc(), new ReadCommandProc());
var printCommand = new Command("print");
var readCommand = new Command("read");

if (commandProc.CanProcess(printCommand)) commandProc.ProcessCommand(printCommand);
if (commandProc.CanProcess(readCommand)) commandProc.ProcessCommand(readCommand);
```

Вариант 2. Если для 1 команды возможен только 1 обработчик. Все, что надо сделать - это написать другой вариант композитного обработчика.

```
public class CompositeCommandProcessorDictionary : ICommandProcessor
{
    Dictionary<string, ICommandProcessor> _processors = new Dictionary<string, ICommandProcessor>();

    public void Register(string commandName, ICommandProcessor processor)
    {
        _processors.Add(commandName, processor);
    }

    public bool CanProcess(ICommand command)
    {
        return _processors.ContainsKey(command.CommandName);
    }

    public void ProcessCommand(ICommand command)
    {
        if (!CanProcess(command)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(command));
        _processors[command.CommandName].ProcessCommand(command);
    }
}
```

Этот вариант основан на словаре, потому не получится заркгистрировать 2 обработчика на команду. Как использовать:

```
var commandProcDict = new CompositeCommandProcessorDictionary();
commandProcDict.Register("print", new PrintCommandProc());
commandProcDict.Register("read", new ReadCommandProc());

var printCommand = new Command("print");
var readCommand = new Command("read");

if (commandProcDict.CanProcess(printCommand)) commandProcDict.ProcessCommand(printCommand);
if (commandProcDict.CanProcess(readCommand)) commandProcDict.ProcessCommand(readCommand);
```

Comment: На мой взгляд, лучше бы было обозвать `ICommand` как-нибудь иначе, например `ICommandTag` или вроде того, т.к. интерфейс с вашим вариантом названия предполагает там наличие объявления еще и метода-выполнителя этой команды, а его там нет. А фактически экземпляр `ICommandProcessor` является исполнителем. Его надо бы тоже обозвать типа `ICommandExecutor`. Ну, это так, мои размышлизмы.

Comment: @Bulson По идее, лучше было бы называть `ICommandArgument` и `ICommand`, но я так не сделал, чтобы не запутать автора вопроса - так как он назвал аргумент команды командой.

Comment: @Bulson а по поводу `CommandExecutor` - так он по сути должен исполнять команду, когда как у мен в коде команды не исполняются, я обрабатываются, потому `CommandProcessor`

Comment: `ICommandArgument` и меня бы запутал :)

Comment: @Bulson Потому я постарался выбрать такие названия, чтобы минимизировать запутанность. Автор вопроса я надеюсь сам переименует типы как ему понравится :)

Comment: Надеюсь, что ваш ответ будет полезен автору вопроса, поглядим сможет ли он воспользоваться им.